# Commander can't handle multiple command arguments

Tags: node.js

I have the following [commander](https://www.npmjs.org/package/commander) command with multiple arguments:

```
var program = require('commander');

program
  .command('rename <id> [name]')
  .action(function() {
    console.log(arguments);
  });

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Using the app yields the following result:

```
$ node app.js 1 "Hello"
{ '0': '1',
  '1':
   { commands: [],
     options: [],
     _execs: [],
     _args: [ [Object] ],
     _name: 'rename',
     parent:
      { commands: [Object],
        options: [],
        _execs: [],
        _args: [],
        _name: 'app',
        Command: [Function: Command],
        Option: [Function: Option],
        _events: [Object],
        rawArgs: [Object],
        args: [Object] } } }
```

As you can see, the action receives the first argument (`<id>`) and `program`, but doesn't receives the second argument: `[name]`.

I've tried:

- Making `[name]` a required argument.
- Passing the name unquoted to the tool from the command line.
- Simplifying my real app into the tiny reproducible program above.
- Using a variadic argument for `name` (`rename <id> [name...]`), but this results on both `1` and `Hello` to being assigned into the same array as the first parameter to action, defeating the purpose of having `id`.

What am I missing? Does commander only accepts one argument per command (doesn't looks so in the documentation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was a bug in an old version of `commander`. This works now with `commander@2.9.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same problems, and decided to use [**Caporal**](https://github.com/mattallty/Caporal.js) instead.

Here's an example from their docs on [Creating a command](https://caporal.io/guide/commands.html#creating-a-command):

> When writing complex programs, you'll likely want to manage multiple commands. Use the `.command()` method to specify them:

```js
program
  // a first command
  .command("my-command", "Optional command description used in help")
  .argument(/* ... */)
  .action(/* ... */)
  // a second command
  .command("sec-command", "...")
  .option(/* ... */)
  .action(/* ... */)
```